# PHP $_GET from url on same page

Tags: php, html

I'm doing some pagination in PHP but i run into some problems. I did pagination, and everything is working well but what i wanted is to add a form on the page in which user could type in how much items he wants on each page. The problem is, when i enter number of pages (eg. 3), it works fine for the first time and lists 3 items, but when i click on "next page" it again lists default number of elements (2). I've searched everything and anything but can't really find what seems to be a problem. I'm kinda new to php so i guess that i don't get some things yet, but I hope it's not too much of a trouble for you to take look at this and tell me what you think. Thanks in advance!
I did it like this:

**form:**

```
<?php
    print("
        <form style='padding-left:5px;' method='get'>Broj komponenti po stranici:<input type='text' name='cpp'   /><input class='button3' type='submit' name='cppb' value='Promijeni' /></form>
    ");
```

**check if there is some thing stored in cpp:**

```
$rec_limit = ($_GET['cpp']);
if(!(isset($_GET['cpp']))) { $rec_limit = 2; } //if there is no  cpp set, let it be 2 (default)
```

**right here is database and pagination part (i don't think that this is the part that makes troubles):**

```
$sql = "SELECT count(id) FROM komponenta ";
$retval = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
if(!$retval) {
    die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
$row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_NUM );
$rec_count = $row[0];
$max_pages = ($rec_count / $rec_limit) -1;


if(isset($_GET{'page'}) ) {
    $page = $_GET{'page'} + 1;
    $offset = $rec_limit * $page ;
} else {
    $page = 0;
    $offset = 0;
}
$left_rec = $rec_count - ($page * $rec_limit);

$sql = "SELECT * ".
    "FROM komponenta ".
    "LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit";

$retval = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
if(!$retval) {
    die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
print("<TABLE class='tablica' border=‘1’>");
print("<TR>");
print("<TD></TD>");
print("<TD>Vrsta</TD>");
print("<TD>Proizvođač</TD>");
print("<TD>Frekv</TD>");
print("<TD>Izlazna</TD>");
print("<TD>Dobavljač</TD>");
print("<TD>Status</TD>");
print("<TD>Datum kupnje</TD>");
print("<TD>Datum zaprimanja</TD>");
print("<TD>Opis</TD>");
print("<TD>Napomena</TD>");
print("<TD>Komada</TD>");
print("<TD>Metara</TD>");
print("</TR>");

$br=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    print("<TR>");
    print("<TD>". $br . "</TD>");
    print("<TD>". $row["1"]. "</TD>");
    print("<TD>" . $row["2"]. "</TD>");
    print("<TD>" . $row["3"]. "</TD>");
    print("<TD>" . $row["4"]. "</TD>");
    print("<TD>" . $row["5"]. "</TD>");
    print("<TD>" . $row["6"]. "</TD>");
    print("<TD>" . $row["7"]. "</TD>");
    print("<TD>" . $row["8"]. "</TD>");
    print("<TD>" . $row["9"]. "</TD>");
    print("<TD>" . $row["10"]. "</TD>");
    print("<TD>" . $row["11"]. "</TD>");
    print("<TD>" . $row["12"]. "</TD>" );
    print("</TR>");
    $br++;
} 
print("</TABLE>");
```

**and here is the part that bothers me:**

```
if( $page >= $max_pages ) {
    $last = $page - 2;
    echo "<b class='paragraf1'>Page: ". $page ." </b><a class='button3' href=\"protected_page.php?page=$last?cpp=$rec_limit\"><text class='buttontxt'>Last " . $rec_limit . " Records</text></a>";
    /*with ?cpp=$rec_limit i set the url
    (when i press "next") to have for eg ..."?cpp=3"... and it does appear so,
    but the $_GET['cpp'] from the beggining of code obviously doesn't read this..
    Well, at least it doesn't store it into $rec_limit*/
} else if($page > 0) {
    $last = $page - 2;
    echo "<b class='paragraf1'>Page: ". $page ." </b><a class='button3' href=\"protected_page.php?page=$last?cpp=$rec_limit\"><text class='buttontxt'>Last " . $rec_limit . " Records</text></a> ";
    echo "<a class='button3' href=\"protected_page.php?page=$page?cpp=$rec_limit\"><text class='buttontxt'>Next " . $rec_limit . " Records</text></a>";
} else if($page == 0) {
    echo "<b class='paragraf1'>Page: ". $page ." </b><a class='button3' href=\"protected_page.php?page=$page?cpp=$rec_limit\"><text class='buttontxt'>Next " . $rec_limit . " Records</text></a>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected_page.php?page=$page?cpp=$rec_limit
```

replace the 2nd `?` by `&`

```
protected_page.php?page=$page&cpp=$rec_limit
```

When you're passing variables in the url after the script name there is a `?` then between each variable and the other it is and `&` that separates.

and at your place I would replace that too:

```
    if(!(isset($_GET['cpp']))){$rec_limit=2;}
```

by:

```
    if(!isset($_GET['cpp']) || (int)$rec_limit<=0){ $rec_limit=2; }
```

Comment: Oh my god, you are kidding me. I literally spent about 3 hours on this. I'm such a noob, I should have known that. Thank you so much man! I love you!

Comment: You saved @user3243547's life while your reputation was 911. That's funny. Now I am going to mess it up by upvoting for sharp eyes.